# Show first n rows sorted by one column but they should be unique by another column (SQLite, Android Room)

Tags: sqlite, android-room

A simple select * from mytable will return below rows. I don't know how to draw table in post so I am adding the image
[image: select * from my_table]

As I mentioned in the question title:
(i) show first n rows sorted by one column (can be achieved using order by)
(ii) but they should be unique by another column (unique by collectionID column)

select * from mytable
order by lastAccessTime DESC;

this sorts the table in descending order according to their lastAccessTime as shown in below image:
[image]

Now I want to filter these rows according to their collectionID. So only 1 row per collectionID. I have added the image. The strikethrough rows should be removed.
[image]

Also, First n rows (lets say 30) should be returned.

I am using Android Room ORM which uses SQLite but to get the desired result set I have to write the correct query.

Comment: If you add images, at least format the images so that they are readable and only contain necessary information (e.g. don't include the column `trackString` which is irrelevant).  You do not need to show all the columns to illustrate the point.  The images are too small, so one has to click on them anyway to see the details which is annoying.  You also don't need to demonstrate what an ORDER BY clause does.  We all know what sorting data looks like.

Comment: @CPerkins I thought may be showing all the columns will help because query may involve another columns. I don't have much experience with SQL.

Comment: The actual data could contain many, many columns, but since the question is about sorting on only one column and filtering by the other, then that's about all that is needed.  The question and answer would not change if you have more columns... unless you are not revealing some important detail about the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a window function filter here. Which will assign a row number based on collectionID and then you can just fetch only 1 row per collectionID. You may give a try to  -

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY collectionID ORDER BY ID DESC) RN
       FROM mytable) T
 WHERE RN = 1
 LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: You have tagged this question as SQLITE and you are trying to execute this on MySQL 5.6 which doesn't support window function. What DB you are using?

Comment: I am using SQLite. I will edit my question and tags

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is to "filter" the data with one query which is the source of another query.  A window function can be used as in the other answer, but a basic sub-query is also sufficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
   INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Max(id) AS singleID, collectionID
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY collectionID) AS filter
   ON mytable.id = filter.singleID
ORDER BY lastAccessTime DESC
LIMIT 30;
```